# Google ComboChart not showing all data rows

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Google ComboChart is not showing all data rows when dealing with larger set of data and when using series type 'bars' and 'lines.'

I'm setting series 2 as type 'bars', but not all data is shown.

If I change series 2 as type 'lines', all data is shown.

Same applies when using simple ColumnChart - if date range is long (~3 years), not all data is shown.

Is there some option that is limiting date range of data?

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);


      function drawVisualization() {
        // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([[{label: 'date', type: 'string'}, {label: 'data1', type: 'number'}, {label: 'data2', type: 'number'}, {label: 'data3', type: 'number'}],['12.09.2011',8901.00,2967.00, null],['13.09.2011',17693.36,2948.89, null],['20.09.2011',28900.00,2890.00, null],['22.09.2011',2850.00,2850.00, null],['26.09.2011',2798.65,2798.65, null],['27.09.2011',5789.00,2894.50, null],['28.09.2011',5600.00,2800.00, null],['03.10.2011',7845.01,2615.00, null],['04.10.2011',5222.00,2611.00, null],['12.10.2011',5230.11,2615.06, null],['13.10.2011',2799.00,2799.00, null],['17.10.2011',2870.00,2870.00, null],['21.10.2011',51840.00,2880.00, null],['24.10.2011',39418.00,2815.57, null],['26.10.2011',16812.06,2802.01, null],['27.10.2011',44100.00,2940.00, null],['28.10.2011',20073.14,2867.59, null],['02.11.2011',2815.02,2815.02, null],['08.11.2011',31421.01,2856.46, null],['10.11.2011',2850.00,2850.00, null],['11.11.2011',20509.00,2929.86, null],['16.11.2011',11689.02,2922.26, null],['23.11.2011',5430.01,2715.01, null],['25.11.2011',14700.02,2450.00, null],['30.11.2011',50399.91,2800.00, null],['01.12.2011',14289.98,2858.00, null],['02.12.2011',2900.00,2900.00, null],['05.12.2011',8290.00,2763.33, null],['19.12.2011',2700.00,2700.00, null],['27.12.2011',132600.00,2600.00, null],['30.12.2011',5450.00,2725.00, null],['04.01.2012',23451.00,2605.67, null],['05.01.2012',69216.00,2563.56, null],['11.01.2012',25840.02,2584.00, null],['13.01.2012',20580.00,2572.50, null],['17.01.2012',12999.97,2599.99, null],['23.01.2012',14825.15,2470.86, null],['27.01.2012',7206.00,2402.00, null],['30.01.2012',5000.00,2500.00, null],['31.01.2012',38997.00,2599.80, null],['06.02.2012',31880.00,2656.67, null],['07.02.2012',26843.00,2684.30, null],['09.02.2012',49530.00,2751.67, null],['15.02.2012',70874.00,2834.96, null],['16.02.2012',35756.00,2979.67, null],['20.02.2012',50484.00,2969.65, null],['21.02.2012',5720.01,2860.01, null],['22.02.2012',161239.76,3042.26, null],['23.02.2012',21063.00,3009.00, null],['24.02.2012',22003.84,3143.41, null],['27.02.2012',15778.72,3155.74, null],['29.02.2012',3195.02,3195.02, null],['01.03.2012',63943.57,3197.18, null],['02.03.2012',6300.00,3150.00, null],['05.03.2012',22019.05,3145.58, null],['06.03.2012',9324.00,3108.00, null],['07.03.2012',30841.04,3084.10, null],['12.03.2012',34095.02,3099.55, null],['13.03.2012',12754.98,3188.75, null],['14.03.2012',180724.39,3409.89, null],['15.03.2012',10495.00,3498.33, null],['16.03.2012',19801.00,3300.17, null],['19.03.2012',34633.00,3463.30, null],['20.03.2012',21380.64,3563.44, null],['21.03.2012',44253.10,3404.08, null],['22.03.2012',47515.13,3393.94, null],['26.03.2012',40574.05,3121.08, null],['28.03.2012',6650.00,3325.00, null],['29.03.2012',6354.08,3177.04, null],['02.04.2012',80078.00,3203.12, null],['04.04.2012',3177.00,3177.00, null],['05.04.2012',27029.34,3378.67, null],['06.04.2012',38417.02,3201.42, null],['10.04.2012',31839.99,3184.00, null],['17.04.2012',48711.00,3247.40, null],['23.04.2012',31545.01,3154.50, null],['24.04.2012',9434.10,3144.70, null],['27.04.2012',6487.96,3243.98, null],['02.05.2012',15977.60,3195.52, null],['03.05.2012',12720.26,3180.07, null],['04.05.2012',9300.02,3100.01, null],['07.05.2012',12350.01,3087.50, null],['09.05.2012',3100.00,3100.00, null],['10.05.2012',6260.01,3130.01, null],['15.05.2012',18155.01,3025.84, null],['16.05.2012',6100.00,3050.00, null],['17.05.2012',71447.09,2976.96, null],['18.05.2012',9268.00,3089.33, null],['23.05.2012',17796.03,2966.01, null],['24.05.2012',20349.15,2907.02, null],['28.05.2012',2911.01,2911.01, null],['29.05.2012',26196.06,2910.67, null],['30.05.2012',25290.09,2810.01, null],['04.06.2012',8100.00,2700.00, null],['12.06.2012',2900.00,2900.00, null],['15.06.2012',10884.09,2721.02, null],['28.06.2012',5464.00,2732.00, null],['03.07.2012',13855.00,2771.00, null],['04.07.2012',56000.00,2800.00, null],['05.07.2012',95127.92,2882.66, null],['06.07.2012',29516.40,2951.64, null],['10.07.2012',33587.00,3053.36, null],['11.07.2012',90906.04,3134.69, null],['12.07.2012',9250.00,3083.33, null],['13.07.2012',31683.36,3168.34, null],['17.07.2012',2971.00,2971.00, null],['18.07.2012',29528.90,3280.99, null],['19.07.2012',12800.00,3200.00, null],['23.07.2012',91070.00,3252.50, null],['24.07.2012',9417.03,3139.01, null],['25.07.2012',25760.00,3220.00, null],['26.07.2012',49776.00,3111.00, null],['27.07.2012',13040.00,3260.00, null],['07.08.2012',138298.00,3292.81, null],['09.08.2012',44871.00,3451.62, null],['13.08.2012',158843.40,3694.03, null],['17.08.2012',3989.00,3989.00, null],['20.08.2012',95843.86,3993.49, null],['21.08.2012',153428.78,3934.07, null],['22.08.2012',3999.99,3999.99, null],['23.08.2012',3730.00,3730.00, null],['24.08.2012',40452.28,3677.48, null],['28.08.2012',248299.60,3598.54, null],['29.08.2012',34690.00,3469.00, null],['30.08.2012',10200.00,3400.00, null],['31.08.2012',35000.00,3500.00, null],['03.09.2012',27200.00,3400.00, null],['04.09.2012',6700.00,3350.00, null],['05.09.2012',3350.00,3350.00, null],['06.09.2012',9750.03,3250.01, null],['10.09.2012',23060.01,3294.29, null],['11.09.2012',40686.99,3390.58, null],['12.09.2012',21149.98,3525.00, null],['13.09.2012',32834.98,3648.33, null],['14.09.2012',21503.00,3583.83, null],['18.09.2012',26765.00,3345.63, null],['20.09.2012',53578.19,3348.64, null],['21.09.2012',19878.00,3313.00, null],['28.09.2012',3400.00,3400.00, null],['02.10.2012',76956.98,3498.04, null],['03.10.2012',112000.00,3500.00, null],['05.10.2012',107512.86,3468.16, null],['09.10.2012',7200.00,3600.00, null],['10.10.2012',3677.98,3677.98, null],['12.10.2012',6900.00,3450.00, null],['15.10.2012',6900.00,3450.00, null],['17.10.2012',3448.00,3448.00, null],['18.10.2012',34426.03,3442.60, null],['19.10.2012',3440.01,3440.01, null],['22.10.2012',31400.00,3488.89, null],['24.10.2012',14000.00,3500.00, null],['26.10.2012',10500.00,3500.00, null],['31.10.2012',154911.37,3442.47, null],['05.11.2012',906760.90,3584.04, null],['06.11.2012',7100.00,3550.00, null],['08.11.2012',3560.00,3560.00, null],['09.11.2012',3550.00,3550.00, null],['15.11.2012',3405.00,3405.00, null],['19.11.2012',7000.00,3500.00, null],['22.11.2012',31500.00,3500.00, null],['27.11.2012',28000.10,3500.01, null],['06.12.2012',3434.00,3434.00, null],['11.12.2012',20400.00,3400.00, null],['13.12.2012',10350.00,3450.00, null],['17.12.2012',44625.89,3432.76, null],['18.12.2012',3595.00,3595.00, null],['20.12.2012',89996.00,3749.83, null],['24.12.2012',11106.00,3702.00, null],['27.12.2012',40916.00,3409.67, null],['28.12.2012',51070.30,3404.69, null],['31.12.2012',7345.00,3672.50, null],['03.01.2013',10501.00,3500.33, null],['04.01.2013',84373.40,3515.56, null],['07.01.2013',47438.00,3649.08, null],['08.01.2013',11200.00,3733.33, null],['09.01.2013',30019.00,3752.38, null],['10.01.2013',297316.96,3861.26, null],['11.01.2013',120499.00,3887.06, null],['14.01.2013',52054.06,3718.15, null],['15.01.2013',56911.00,3794.07, null],['16.01.2013',38020.00,3802.00, null],['18.01.2013',4.00,3800.00, null],['21.01.2013',65926.98,3878.06, null],['22.01.2013',42602.00,3872.91, null],['23.01.2013',162577.50,4064.44, null],['24.01.2013',50545.00,4212.08, null],['25.01.2013',25160.00,4193.33, null],['29.01.2013',4160.00,4160.00, null],['30.01.2013',4000.00,4000.00, null],['01.02.2013',26410.00,3772.86, null],['04.02.2013',69103.13,3839.06, null],['05.02.2013',7800.00,3900.00, null],['06.02.2013',214800.00,3977.78, null],['07.02.2013',82827.47,3944.17, null],['08.02.2013',48499.95,4041.66, null],['11.02.2013',92148.92,4188.59, null],['12.02.2013',77960.09,4103.16, null],['14.02.2013',48780.98,4065.08, null],['19.02.2013',28000.00,4000.00, null],['22.02.2013',28050.01,4007.14, null],['25.02.2013',71345.47,4196.79, null],['26.02.2013',8300.00,4150.00, null],['28.02.2013',8102.10,4051.05, null],['05.03.2013',33150.00,4143.75, null],['06.03.2013',234162.79,4257.51, null],['07.03.2013',30983.00,4426.14, null],['13.03.2013',26100.01,4350.00, null],['14.03.2013',108446.01,4337.84, null],['15.03.2013',64800.00,4320.00, null],['18.03.2013',12960.00,4320.00, null],['19.03.2013',51621.00,4301.75, null],['21.03.2013',12862.00,4287.33, null],['22.03.2013',4300.00,4300.00, null],['29.03.2013',51521.00,4293.42, null],['02.04.2013',43000.00,4300.00, null],['03.04.2013',12621.02,4207.01, null],['04.04.2013',4300.00,4300.00, null],['08.04.2013',25210.04,4201.67, null],['09.04.2013',56052.18,4003.73, null],['10.04.2013',8600.00,4300.00, null],['12.04.2013',8110.02,4055.01, null],['15.04.2013',8100.03,4050.02, null],['19.04.2013',85413.69,4270.68, null],['23.04.2013',16640.04,4160.01, null],['29.04.2013',69424.00,4083.76, null],['02.05.2013',175913.06,3909.18, null],['03.05.2013',19037.06,3807.41, null],['07.05.2013',50250.88,3865.45, null],['09.05.2013',3840.00,3840.00, null],['10.05.2013',36000.00,4000.00, null],['13.05.2013',28000.00,4000.00, null],['14.05.2013',36000.00,4000.00, null],['15.05.2013',4000.00,4000.00, null],['16.05.2013',4020.00,4020.00, null],['17.05.2013',40170.01,4017.00, null],['21.05.2013',8000.00,4000.00, null],['22.05.2013',28000.00,4000.00, null],['03.06.2013',18780.10,3756.02, null],['07.06.2013',48851.01,3757.77, null],['11.06.2013',18540.13,3708.03, null],['12.06.2013',11100.00,3700.00, null],['13.06.2013',14400.10,3600.03, null],['14.06.2013',47200.00,3933.33, null],['17.06.2013',24293.91,4048.99, null],['19.06.2013',19800.00,3960.00, null],['20.06.2013',7600.00,3800.00, null],['21.06.2013',22778.00,3796.33, null],['26.06.2013',83600.00,3800.00, null],['27.06.2013',18572.00,3714.40, null],['01.07.2013',38000.00,3800.00, null],['08.07.2013',7400.00,3700.00, null],['09.07.2013',80476.30,3658.01, null],['10.07.2013',14400.42,3600.11, null],['11.07.2013',14798.00,3699.50, null],['12.07.2013',32073.29,3563.70, null],['16.07.2013',3540.00,3540.00, null],['17.07.2013',3611.02,3611.02, null],['22.07.2013',3553924.46,3600.73, null],['26.07.2013',36000.08,3600.01, null],['29.07.2013',51434.10,3598.14, null],['30.07.2013',14779.14,3597.05, null],['31.07.2013',390648.30,3551.35, null],['01.08.2013',3580000.00,3580.00, null],['07.08.2013',31784.05,3531.56, null],['08.08.2013',7200.00,3600.00, null],['13.08.2013',44623.97,3718.66, null],['16.08.2013',3700.00,3700.00, null],['20.08.2013',7280.00,3640.00, null],['22.08.2013',41622.00,3783.82, null],['23.08.2013',86721.00,3770.48, null],['26.08.2013',22430.01,3738.34, null],['28.08.2013',3750.00,3750.00, null],['04.09.2013',19597.31,3919.46, null],['05.09.2013',19150.00,3830.00, null],['06.09.2013',198452.00,3744.38, null],['09.09.2013',3800.00,3800.00, null],['10.09.2013',11697.00,3899.00, null],['11.09.2013',11697.00,3899.00, null],['12.09.2013',11550.00,3850.00, null],['13.09.2013',19649.00,3929.80, null],['16.09.2013',7850.00,3925.00, null],['17.09.2013',250170.00,3848.77, null],['18.09.2013',19479.97,3895.99, null],['19.09.2013',70200.00,3900.00, null],['20.09.2013',19495.97,3899.19, null],['23.09.2013',11738.00,3912.67, null],['24.09.2013',15696.00,3924.00, null],['25.09.2013',157235.00,3835.00, null],['26.09.2013',11401.00,3800.33, null],['27.09.2013',7600.00,3800.00, null],['30.09.2013',7799.88,3899.94, null],['01.10.2013',93620.20,3744.81, null],['02.10.2013',11669.94,3889.98, null],['03.10.2013',7779.96,3889.98, null],['04.10.2013',7500.00,3750.00, null],['07.10.2013',60527.01,3782.94, null],['09.10.2013',3755.00,3755.00, null],['10.10.2013',7700.00,3850.00, null],['11.10.2013',7760.00,3880.00, null],['14.10.2013',11569.98,3856.66, null],['15.10.2013',7759.98,3879.99, null],['16.10.2013',11639.93,3879.98, null],['17.10.2013',38799.85,3879.99, null],['18.10.2013',39317.96,3931.80, null],['21.10.2013',3968.60,3968.60, null],['22.10.2013',7937.10,3968.55, null],['23.10.2013',11925.58,3975.19, null],['24.10.2013',30171.43,3771.43, null],['25.10.2013',15600.00,3900.00, null],['28.10.2013',7940.00,3970.00, null],['29.10.2013',41374.50,3761.32, null],['30.10.2013',10750.00,3583.33, null],['31.10.2013',11195.00,3731.67, null],['04.11.2013',7539.99,3770.00, null],['05.11.2013',3774.00,3774.00, null],['06.11.2013',14603.01,3650.75, null],['07.11.2013',7499.00,3749.50, null],['08.11.2013',3769.99,3769.99, null],['11.11.2013',83914.09,3648.44, null],['12.11.2013',7499.00,3749.50, null],['13.11.2013',21712.02,3618.67, null],['14.11.2013',173380.35,3538.37, null],['15.11.2013',3608.01,3608.01, null],['18.11.2013',21360.00,3560.00, null],['19.11.2013',21000.06,3500.01, null],['20.11.2013',7336.02,3668.01, null],['21.11.2013',3668.01,3668.01, null],['22.11.2013',3686.00,3686.00, null],['25.11.2013',7374.99,3687.50, null],['26.11.2013',7377.98,3688.99, null],['27.11.2013',569800.00,3700.00, null],['28.11.2013',3700.00,3700.00, null],['29.11.2013',7399.98,3699.99, null],['02.12.2013',3699.99,3699.99, null],['03.12.2013',21738.06,3623.01, null],['04.12.2013',3600.00,3600.00, null],['05.12.2013',67496.34,3552.44, null],['06.12.2013',150756.01,3505.95, null],['09.12.2013',13975.00,3493.75, null],['11.12.2013',86653.70,3466.15, null],['12.12.2013',24180.10,3454.30, null],['16.12.2013',7000.00,3500.00, null],['17.12.2013',38500.00,3500.00, null],['18.12.2013',10766.68,3588.89, null],['19.12.2013',3588.80,3588.80, null],['20.12.2013',20945.01,3490.84, null],['23.12.2013',199809.51,3632.90, null],['27.12.2013',36589.04,3658.90, null],['30.12.2013',276531.42,3736.91, null],['31.12.2013',74816.54,3740.83, null],['02.01.2014',7599.98,3799.99, null],['03.01.2014',11273.18,3757.73, null],['07.01.2014',59199.97,3700.00, null],['08.01.2014',635615.72,3591.05, null],['09.01.2014',367406.55,3602.03, null],['10.01.2014',183574.01,3599.49, null],['13.01.2014',28409.03,3551.13, null],['14.01.2014',25010.80,3572.97, null],['15.01.2014',24777.98,3539.71, null],['16.01.2014',145499.41,3548.77, null],['17.01.2014',63248.64,3513.81, null],['20.01.2014',24524.24,3503.46, null],['21.01.2014',67478.99,3551.53, null],['22.01.2014',81572.19,3546.62, null],['23.01.2014',13965.00,3491.25, null],['24.01.2014',56729.01,3545.56, null],['28.01.2014',120344.00,3646.79, null],['29.01.2014',72365.00,3618.25, null],['30.01.2014',113490.05,3546.56, null],['31.01.2014',7195.98,3597.99, null],['03.02.2014',151627.06,3526.21, null],['04.02.2014',77612.08,3527.82, null],['05.02.2014',10740.00,3580.00, null],['06.02.2014',125314.49,3580.41, null],['07.02.2014',7216.00,3608.00, null],['10.02.2014',46310.00,3562.31, null],['11.02.2014',24842.02,3548.86, null],['13.02.2014',103820.00,3580.00, null],['14.02.2014',91770.06,3529.62, null],['17.02.2014',7139.66,3569.83, null],['18.02.2014',10555.03,3518.34, null],['19.02.2014',7099.46,3549.73, null],['20.02.2014',42578.00,3548.17, null],['21.02.2014',7100.00,3550.00, null],['24.02.2014',132156.09,3477.79, null],['25.02.2014',24366.24,3480.89, null],['26.02.2014',739002.95,3405.54, null],['27.02.2014',44459.99,3420.00, null],['28.02.2014',10259.98,3419.99, null],['03.03.2014',59907.02,3328.17, null],['04.03.2014',60088.99,3338.28, null],['05.03.2014',85538.20,3289.93, null],['06.03.2014',89702.32,3203.65, null],['07.03.2014',3328.88,3328.88, null],['10.03.2014',25875.59,3234.45, null],['12.03.2014',35042.30,3185.66, null],['14.03.2014',133441.13,3254.66, null],['17.03.2014',57834.33,3213.02, null],['18.03.2014',16160.10,3232.02, null],['19.03.2014',6580.00,3290.00, null],['21.03.2014',35719.00,3247.18, null],['24.03.2014',83470.00,3210.38, null],['25.03.2014',142265.00,3308.49, null],['26.03.2014',62943.20,3312.80, null],['27.03.2014',16935.66,3387.13, null],['01.04.2014',128422.90,3379.55, null],['03.04.2014',64402.00,3389.58, null],['04.04.2014',30501.00,3389.00, null],['07.04.2014',52819.08,3301.19, null],['09.04.2014',3300.00,3300.00, null],['15.04.2014',80173.13,3206.93, null],['16.04.2014',28502.00,3166.89, null],['18.04.2014',13000.00,3250.00, null],['28.04.2014',25206.15,3150.77, null],['29.04.2014',6387.93,3193.97, null],['30.04.2014',89489.43,3085.84, null],['02.05.2014',36059.00,3004.92, null],['05.05.2014',136634.21,2907.11, null],['08.05.2014',11453.05,2863.26, null],['09.05.2014',5865.99,2933.00, null],['12.05.2014',29144.52,2914.45, null],['13.05.2014',26940.99,2993.44, null],['14.05.2014',11728.12,2932.03, null],['15.05.2014',49405.76,2906.22, null],['16.05.2014',32056.05,2914.19, null],['21.05.2014',55955.83,2797.79, null],['22.05.2014',11243.90,2810.98, null],['26.05.2014',92501.43,2890.67, null],['28.05.2014',5795.98,2897.99, null],['29.05.2014',68444.93,2851.87, null],['02.06.2014',8428.53,2809.51, null],['03.06.2014',28092.47,2809.25, null],['04.06.2014',14085.04,2817.01, null],['06.06.2014',2800.03,2800.03, null],['09.06.2014',5789.60,2894.80, null],['10.06.2014',31968.05,2906.19, null],['11.06.2014',50176.02,2951.53, null],['13.06.2014',67871.18,2827.97, null],['16.06.2014',14198.77,2839.75, null],['18.06.2014',5920.00,2960.00, null],['20.06.2014',29529.70,2952.97, null],['23.06.2014',31367.44,2851.59, null],['24.06.2014',5919.89,2959.95, null],['26.06.2014',316756.81,3045.74, null],['27.06.2014',87289.97,3010.00, null],['30.06.2014',38045.98,2926.61, null],['08.07.2014',25590.53,2843.39, null],['10.07.2014',8607.01,2869.00, null],['11.07.2014',8349.02,2783.01, null],['14.07.2014',68505.15,2740.21, null],['15.07.2014',24554.81,2728.31, null],['17.07.2014',16522.10,2753.68, null],['18.07.2014',17099.28,2849.88, null],['21.07.2014',17076.99,2846.17, null],['23.07.2014',20174.51,2882.07, null],['25.07.2014',36778.00,2829.08, null],['28.07.2014',2890.00,2890.00, null],['29.07.2014',14449.00,2889.80, null],['30.07.2014',11575.70,2893.93, null],['31.07.2014',17328.00,2888.00, null],['04.08.2014',5607.00,2803.50, null],['08.08.2014',41765.45,2784.36, null],['11.08.2014',11389.80,2847.45, null],['14.08.2014',16800.32,2800.05, null],['18.08.2014',13931.28,2786.26, null],['19.08.2014',30429.00,2766.27, null],['21.08.2014',11173.87,2793.47, null],['22.08.2014',19425.00,2775.00, null],['26.08.2014',8482.90,2827.63, null],['27.08.2014',33943.90,2828.66, null],['28.08.2014',13161262.62,2949.63, null],['29.08.2014',29879.80,2987.98, null],['01.09.2014',2980.00,2980.00, null],['03.09.2014',176917.09,2808.21, null],['04.09.2014',279173.18,2848.71, null],['05.09.2014',199712.14,2894.38, null],['08.09.2014',37701.00,2900.08, null],['09.09.2014',254355.79,2857.93, null],['10.09.2014',87778.22,2831.56, null],['11.09.2014',2849.99,2849.99, null],['12.09.2014',86949.85,2804.83, null],['15.09.2014',2847.97,2847.97, null],['16.09.2014',166566.09,2823.15, null],['17.09.2014',5700.00,2850.00, null],['18.09.2014',14150.00,2830.00, null],['19.09.2014',19849.50,2835.64, null],['22.09.2014',14199.99,2840.00, null],['23.09.2014',70005.08,2800.20, null],['24.09.2014',338981.13,2801.50, null],['25.09.2014',221199.51,2799.99, null],['26.09.2014',63699.57,2769.55, null],['29.09.2014',5640.00,2820.00, null],['30.09.2014',2859.90,2859.90, null],['01.10.2014',128800.00,2800.00, null],['02.10.2014',1623278.42,2823.09, null],['03.10.2014',1569624.84,2906.71, null],['06.10.2014',132023.96,3000.54, null],['07.10.2014',41789.14,2984.94, null],['09.10.2014',655929.65,2954.64, null],['10.10.2014',285681.36,3071.84, null],['13.10.2014',341861.28,3025.32, null],['14.10.2014',15102.00,3020.40, null],['15.10.2014',290271.14,2961.95, null],['16.10.2014',127609.42,2900.21, null],['17.10.2014',29225.22,2922.52, null],['20.10.2014',50966.92,2998.05, null],['21.10.2014',9056.97,3018.99, null],['22.10.2014',6035.52,3017.76, null],['23.10.2014',9050.79,3016.93, null],['27.10.2014',230299.48,2915.18, null],['28.10.2014',9020.00,3006.67, null],['29.10.2014',35511.96,2959.33, null],['30.10.2014',2983.00,2983.00, null],['31.10.2014',8910.00,2970.00, null],['03.11.2014',11877.73,2969.43, null],['04.11.2014',51850.97,2880.61, null],['05.11.2014',22965.88,2870.74, null],['06.11.2014',2900.00,2900.00, null],['07.11.2014',5800.00,2900.00, null],['10.11.2014',20040.04,2862.86, null],['11.11.2014',5800.00,2900.00, null],['12.11.2014',8700.00,2900.00, null],['13.11.2014',8612.10,2870.70, null],['14.11.2014',91200.04,2850.00, null],['17.11.2014',62205.00,2827.50, null],['18.11.2014',2869.00,2869.00, null],['19.11.2014',2868.88,2868.88, null],['20.11.2014',282868.12,2800.67, null],['21.11.2014',5736.78,2868.39, null],['24.11.2014',5738.00,2869.00, null],['25.11.2014',475557.92,2764.87, null],['26.11.2014',144687.50,2782.45, null],['27.11.2014',5699.99,2850.00, null],['28.11.2014',189405.05,2785.37, null],['01.12.2014',165319.78,2802.03, null],['02.12.2014',5700.00,2850.00, null],['03.12.2014',37129.59,2856.12, null],['04.12.2014',58133.51,2906.68, null],['08.12.2014',8706.90,2902.30, null],['09.12.2014',22970.00,2871.25, null],['10.12.2014',14364.00,2872.80, null],['11.12.2014',60900.00,2900.00, null],['12.12.2014',14567.80,2913.56, null],['15.12.2014',64048.44,2911.29, null],['16.12.2014',63800.00,2900.00, null],['17.12.2014',50559.78,2974.10, null],['18.12.2014',5920.00,2960.00, null],['19.12.2014',5960.00,2980.00, null],['22.12.2014',8837.40,2945.80, null],['30.12.2014',14764.95,2952.99, null],['31.12.2014',49704.00,2923.76, null],['02.01.2015',14756.00,2951.20, null],['05.01.2015',169712.07,2977.40, null],['07.01.2015',20688.50,2955.50, null],['08.01.2015',30147.51,3014.75, null],['09.01.2015',26680.15,2964.46, null],['12.01.2015',94847.30,2963.98, null],['13.01.2015',14776.32,2955.26, null],['14.01.2015',449995.50,2999.97, null],['15.01.2015',5917.03,2958.52, null],['16.01.2015',5967.98,2983.99, null],['19.01.2015',8844.83,2948.28, null],['21.01.2015',158149.94,2928.70, null],['22.01.2015',5880.00,2940.00, null],['23.01.2015',8771.94,2923.98, null],['26.01.2015',14428.16,2885.63, null],['27.01.2015',5850.00,2925.00, null],['29.01.2015',104246.36,2817.47, null],['03.02.2015',2895.00,2895.00, null],['06.02.2015',14172.35,2834.47, null],['12.02.2015',217521.26,2753.43, null],['16.02.2015',42715.78,2847.72, null],['17.02.2015',149334.86,2871.82, null],['18.02.2015',281230.81,2899.29, null],['20.02.2015',28962.00,2896.20, null],['23.02.2015',59300.00,2965.00, null],['24.02.2015',38544.81,2964.99, null],['26.02.2015',31843.00,2894.82, null],['27.02.2015',8700.00,2900.00, null],['04.03.2015',5880.00,2940.00, null],['06.03.2015',14463.00,2892.60, null],['09.03.2015',58259.90,2913.00, null],['11.03.2015',8841.87,2947.29, null],['12.03.2015',23575.17,2946.90, null],['13.03.2015',26537.45,2948.61, null],['18.03.2015',26418.00,2935.33, null],['24.03.2015',2935.49,2935.49, null],['07.04.2015',48003.08,2823.71, null],['09.04.2015',39740.73,2838.62, null],['15.04.2015',43077.14,2871.81, null],['17.04.2015',28490.54,2849.05, null],['24.04.2015',11399.96,2849.99, null],['27.04.2015',16904.82,2817.47, null],['28.04.2015',19950.00,2850.00, null],['29.04.2015',17190.00,2865.00, null],['30.04.2015',57852.59,2892.63, null],['07.05.2015',86860.32,2801.95, null],['13.05.2015',8625.98,2875.33, null],['14.05.2015',8538.00,2846.00, null],['20.05.2015',11399.96,2849.99, null],['22.05.2015',81368.70,2805.82, null],['26.05.2015',8519.97,2839.99, null],['27.05.2015',2830.00,2830.00, null],['28.05.2015',5699.62,2849.81, null],['29.05.2015',97513.10,2786.09, null],['01.06.2015',19600.00,2800.00, null],['02.06.2015',131054.08,2788.38, null],['08.06.2015',24959.86,2773.32, null],['09.06.2015',30818.28,2801.66, null],['10.06.2015',11199.88,2799.97, null],['11.06.2015',33595.21,2799.60, null],['15.06.2015',75473.63,2795.32, null],['17.06.2015',157289.94,2808.75, null],['18.06.2015',126949.92,2821.11, null],['19.06.2015',36840.70,2833.90, null],['26.06.2015',8669.67,2889.89, null],['29.06.2015',126881.03,2819.58, null],['30.06.2015',28075.22,2807.52, null],['01.07.2015',84318.94,2810.63, null],['02.07.2015',75378.98,2791.81, null],['03.07.2015',5600.00,2800.00, null],['06.07.2015',14000.00,2800.00, null],['07.07.2015',30919.91,2810.90, null],['09.07.2015',11290.23,2822.56, null],['13.07.2015',16987.82,2831.30, null],['14.07.2015',195402.67,2873.57, null],['16.07.2015',14293.25,2858.65, null],['20.07.2015',45217.29,2826.08, null],['22.07.2015',2895.54,2895.54, null],['24.07.2015',17157.52,2859.59, null],['27.07.2015',28253.70,2825.37, null],['28.07.2015',8499.96,2833.32, null],['29.07.2015',90013.22,2812.91, null],['03.08.2015',14094.99,2819.00, null],['06.08.2015',14210.00,2842.00, null],['10.08.2015',50464.71,2803.60, null],['17.08.2015',14079.98,2816.00, null],['20.08.2015',8486.81,2828.94, null],['21.08.2015',14102.88,2820.58, null],['24.08.2015',96942.62,2769.79, null],['25.08.2015',8302.94,2767.65, null],['27.08.2015',13762.00,2752.40, null],['31.08.2015',153443.49,2645.58, null],['01.09.2015',13629.94,2725.99, null],['02.09.2015',13725.00,2745.00, null],['14.09.2015',13500.00,2700.00, null],['17.09.2015',78589.79,2619.66, null],['21.09.2015',13117.87,2623.57, null],['23.09.2015',51440.04,2572.00, null],['24.09.2015',7710.33,2570.11, null],['29.09.2015',17899.00,2557.00, null],['01.10.2015',2598.99,2598.99, null],['02.10.2015',2522.00,2522.00, null],['05.10.2015',41597.98,2599.87, null],['13.10.2015',10512.00,2628.00, null],['15.10.2015',41104.20,2569.01, null],['19.10.2015',170859.86,2588.79, null],['20.10.2015',34069.37,2620.72, null],['21.10.2015',154359.93,2616.27, null],['22.10.2015',2677.34,2677.34, null],['23.10.2015',181317.94,2706.24, null],['26.10.2015',108040.40,2701.01, null],['27.10.2015',617770.82,2709.52, null],['28.10.2015',105427.06,2849.38, null],['30.10.2015',64027.71,2783.81, null],['02.11.2015',61029.97,2774.09, null],['03.11.2015',32868.95,2739.08, null],['09.11.2015',42364.12,2824.27, null],['10.11.2015',8343.21,2781.07, null],['11.11.2015',8489.79,2829.93, null],['12.11.2015',22240.08,2780.01, null],['13.11.2015',27845.00,2784.50, null],['25.11.2015',46729.86,2748.82, null],['30.11.2015',27094.22,2709.42, null],['01.12.2015',5595.94,2797.97, null],['07.12.2015',13694.92,2738.98, null],['14.12.2015',5589.72,2794.86, null],['18.12.2015',47928.95,2662.72, null],['21.12.2015',35093.71,2699.52, null],['28.12.2015',2779.93,2779.93, null],['29.12.2015',2777.70,2777.70, null],['30.12.2015',41141.49,2742.77, null],['04.01.2016',15930.39,2655.07, null],['08.01.2016',2556.20,2556.20, null],['13.01.2016',7740.11,2580.04, null],['14.01.2016',23220.00,2580.00, null],['19.01.2016',63170.18,2526.81, null],['21.01.2016',74712.75,2490.43, null],['25.01.2016',13240.75,2648.15, null],['26.01.2016',26452.05,2645.21, null],['27.01.2016',26488.90,2648.89, null],['29.01.2016',13243.95,2648.79, null],['01.02.2016',18340.00,2620.00, null],['03.02.2016',66195.05,2647.80, null],['04.02.2016',93840.86,2681.17, null],['09.02.2016',2770.00,2770.00, null],['15.02.2016',10760.79,2690.20, null],['16.02.2016',11099.42,2774.86, null],['17.02.2016',8391.90,2797.30, null],['18.02.2016',41917.00,2794.47, null],['22.02.2016',27359.03,2735.90, null],['29.02.2016',28304.73,2830.47, null],['04.03.2016',5670.00,2835.00, null],['08.03.2016',5671.65,2835.83, null],['09.03.2016',11213.08,2803.27, null],['16.03.2016',116990.48,2658.87, null],['18.03.2016',11020.49,2755.12, null],['21.03.2016',5498.98,2749.49, null],['31.03.2016',16209.38,2701.56, null],['01.04.2016',10804.00,2701.00, null],['04.04.2016',101067.99,2731.57, null],['05.04.2016',13500.00,2700.00, null],['06.04.2016',21917.75,2739.72, null],['11.04.2016',48711.06,2706.17, null],['12.04.2016',2700.00,2700.00, null],['15.04.2016',16200.00,2700.00, null],['18.04.2016',8100.00,2700.00, null],['19.04.2016',8058.15,2686.05, null],['21.04.2016',27000.00,2700.00, null],['29.04.2016',2748.87,2748.87, null],['02.05.2016',2665.01,2665.01, null],['04.05.2016',2726.00,2726.00, null],['05.05.2016',49588.99,2754.94, null],['06.05.2016',479562.99,2837.65, null],['09.05.2016',36530.09,2810.01, null],['10.05.2016',25248.00,2805.33, null],['17.05.2016',25200.00,2800.00, null],['19.05.2016',20299.99,2900.00, null],['23.05.2016',17200.00,2866.67, null],['24.05.2016',11626.12,2906.53, null],['30.05.2016',28404.23,2840.42, null],['31.05.2016',39256.86,2804.06, null],['06.06.2016',5700.00,2850.00, null],['13.06.2016',11198.38,2799.60, null],['14.06.2016',2869.37,2869.37, null],['23.06.2016',30304.31,2754.94, null],['24.06.2016',8279.70,2759.90, null],['27.06.2016',2712.46,2712.46, null],['29.06.2016',11200.00,2800.00, null],['14.07.2016',13900.00,2780.00, null],['21.07.2016',8370.00,2790.00, null],['25.07.2016',2715.00,2715.00, null],['29.07.2016',53069.90,2793.15, null],['01.08.2016',24741.00,2749.00, null],['02.08.2016',5580.00,2790.00, null],['11.08.2016',13725.09,2745.02, null],['12.08.2016',2789.99,2789.99, null],['18.08.2016',8250.00,2750.00, null],['22.08.2016',125839.89,2796.44, null],['23.08.2016',25560.00,2840.00, null]]
      );

    var options = {
      title : 'w00t',
      vAxis: {title: ''},
      hAxis: {title: ''},
      seriesType: 'lines',
      series: {2: {type: 'bars'}},
      
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
       <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: Try removing hard-coded size from style attribute on div

Comment: @WhiteHat I did that, no change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in chart_div (div that contains Google Chart) width - it's fixed on 900px, and all that data (columns) does not fit into that width. You have to extend width manually.